# GMap.NET route is returning null

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm working on a programme with C# and I want to calculate the route, but it's returning null.

Here's my code ;

```
PointLatLng start = new PointLatLng(38.481858, 27.089006);
PointLatLng end = new PointLatLng(38.468447, 27.113793);

MapRoute route = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider
                                      .Instance.GetRoute(start, end, false, false, 15);
GMapRoute r = new GMapRoute(route.Points , "My route");
GMapOverlay routeOverlay = new GMapOverlay("route");
routeOverlay.Routes.Add(r);
gMap.Overlays.Add(routeOverlay);
double distance;
distance = route.Distance;

r.Stroke.Width = 2;
r.Stroke.Color = Color.OrangeRed;
```

I don't know where I am making mistakes. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried passing in the strings of the adresses?

Comment: @nozzleman can you give me an example please?

Comment: try this ::if (route == null)
{
List lstPoints = new List {start ,end};
route = new MapRoute (lstPoints);

Comment: GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute("broadway, new york city", "15th street, new york city", false, false, 15);

Comment: @nozzleman it also returns null plus I have to work with coordinates..

Comment: @sakir it didn't work..

Comment: what does it mean "didnt work" ?  U get null exception again??

Comment: @sakir MapRoute only accepts MapRoute(string)

Comment: @nozzleman,sakir, I found the problem.. The routing service was been removed by google recently..

Comment: is there any workaround?

Comment: @nozzleman If you don't need to get the route's distance value, you can use GetDirections. I couldn't manage to find any other solutions on WinForm using Google Map Service, but now I'm using BingMapProvider with Devexpress Extension on VS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is solved.. The reason why route returns null is because the routing service was been removed by google.

Comment: What is the replacment then?

Answer (score 5):

```
GDirections ss;
var xx = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetDirections(out ss, start, end, false, false, false, false, false);
GMapRoute r = new GMapRoute(ss.Route, "My route");
```

Try this...

Comment: I was trying to get the distance from the route, I don't need directions but thanks for suggestion

Comment: @Vinicious Did this code work for you?On codeplex forums they told me that google has removed routing service. [link](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/642101)

Comment: this give Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on this line: GMapRoute r = new GMapRoute(ss.Route, "My route");

Comment: This gives me the same error - ss ends up being null.

Answer (score 1):

Your Api key is invalid 
Add GMap from nuget
use this code :

```
 public static double GetDistanceByRoute(double startLat, double startLng, double endLat, double endLng)
    {
        GoogleMapProvider.Instance.ApiKey = "Your Api Key";
        PointLatLng start = new PointLatLng(startLat, startLng);
        PointLatLng end = new PointLatLng(endLat, endLng);
        MapRoute route = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(start, end, false, false, 15);
        return route.Distance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        PointLatLng startp = new PointLatLng(-25.974134, 32.593042);
        PointLatLng endp = new PointLatLng(-25.959048, 32.592827);
        MapRoute route = BingMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(startp, endp, false, false, 15);
        GMapRoute r = new GMapRoute(route.Points,"Myroutes");
        GMapOverlay routesOverlay = new GMapOverlay("Myroutes");
        routesOverlay.Routes.Add(r);
        gmap.Overlays.Add(routesOverlay);
        r.Stroke.Width = 2;
        r.Stroke.Color = Color.SeaGreen;
```

//use BingMapProvider

Answer (score 0):

Your API key is missing, i had the same problem, added the api key and it works fine.